# MySQLi result null second time I use it

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to run a second query using the results of my first query to set a flag for all the rows that were just retrieved. The first time I use my result to output JSON it works fine, but the second time I try to call `fetch_assoc()` from it, the array comes back NULL.

```
        $result = API::$connection->query($query);

        if (!mysqli_error(API::$connection))
        {
            API::setHeader(200);
            // return json encoded results

                        /// This works just fine, outputs JSON
            echo JSONizer::jsonEncodeSqlResultWithKeys( $result, array (
                                                                'pId',
                                                                'sender',
                                                                'receiver',
                                                                'content',
                                                                'notified',
                                                                'opened',
                                                                'time' ) );

            // initial update query
            $query = 'UPDATE messages
                    SET received=1
                    WHERE ';

            // start by cycling through each pId received and tack each onto query
            $counter = 0;

                            // this never runs because the associated array returns NULL now
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
            {
                $pId = $row['pId'];

                // concat query
                $query .= 'pId='.$pId;

                // if there's still more to go, tack on OR
                if ($counter++ != count($result))
                {
                    $query .= ' OR';
                }
                else 
                {
                    $query .= ';';
                }

            }
```

I've tried object and procedural style on calling `fetch_assoc`, did not make a difference. I tried copying the result into another variable to use, but that was NULL as well. Why would this only work once, but not a second time.

Comment: Seems like you're using a mixture of procedural and OOP styles of mysqli, not sure they're compatible. Assuming that `API::$connection` is an instance of a connected `MySQLi` object, you would want to change your code to say `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`. See "Example 1" on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php then see if you still have issues

Comment: @wwarren That's what I was doing initially but it was giving me the same problem

Comment: Does the query you're running return anything? What does `$result->num_rows` report?